# Getting "A required parameter (id) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths" error in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a problem with the `getStaticPaths` function.
When I try to get a dynamic display with a parameter it shows me as error: ***A required parameter (id) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for / movies / [id]*** but if I use the other way above it works. Above all I am the documentation.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';


function MovieSelect({movie}){

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Test: {movie.name}</h1>
            <p>{movie.summary.replace(/<[/]?[pb]>/g, '')}</p>
            {movie.image ? <img src={movie.image.medium} /> : null}
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticPaths(){
    const request  = await fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=batman')
    const movies = await request.json()

    //const paths = movies.map(movie =>`/movies/${movie.show.id}`)

    const paths = movies.map(movie =>({
        params: {id: movie.show.id},
    }))

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps({params}){
    const request = await fetch(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${params.id}`)
    const movie = await request.json()

    return{
        props:{
            movie
        }
    }
}

export default MovieSelect
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**A required parameter (id) was not provided as a *string* in getStaticPaths for / movies / [id]**

id should be a string as suggested by the error. Upon hitting the api from your browser, you can see that the id is not a string but a number. You need to convert it to string.

```
params: {id: movie.show.id.toString()},
```

Comment: Why does Next require it to be a string ?

Comment: Because it takes from the url, `3` or `slug` would be number or string?, so string is the choice

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was actually passing the Integer instead of String. Thanks a lottt

Comment: Thank you! I don't think I would have ever figured this one out.

Answer (score 8):

My problem generated the same error, but I had a different bug.

**TL;DR: The name of my file needed to match the key of the slug used in the params object.**

In my case, my file name was `[postSlug].js`. Therefore, the key should have been `postSlug` inside of `getStaticPaths()`.

```
// In [postSlug].js

const pathsWithParams = slugs.map((slugs) => ({ params: { postSlug: slug } })); // <-- postSlug is right
const pathsWithParams = slugs.map((slugs) => ({ params: { id: slug } })); // <--- id is wrong
```

My entire function then looked like this

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const slugs = await getAllBlogSlugs();
    const pathsWithParams = slugs.map((slug) => ({ params: { postSlug: slug } }));

    return {
        paths: pathsWithParams,
        fallback: "blocking",
    };
}
```

**References:**

- [NextJS.org Get Static Paths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths)

Answer (score -2):

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query, locale }) {
const { id } = query;
if (!id) return { notFound: true };
return {
   props: {
     fallback: true,
     query,
     locale,
     ...(await serverSideTranslations(
     locale,
     ["common", "header", "footer"],
     nextI18nextConfig
    )),
   },
 };
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is about an error in static generation of dynamic paths with `getStaticPaths`. How does this solve the issue?